# Make one bean the default spring bean

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, dependency-injection

I have 3 beans of the javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory.

```
@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory()  {       
          //Make this the default bean
}
```

This is the exception I get.

```
No qualifying bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory' available: expected single matching bean but found 3
```

How do I make the above bean the default bean where there are multiple beans of the same type?

Comment: add `@Primary` to the method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that `@Primary` annotation will be enough in this case.

Check [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Primary.html).

Answer (score 2):

You can also define a `@Bean` name and use a `@Qualifier` annotation in order to inject the bean dependency.

For example:

```
@Bean(name="first")
MyBean getFirstBean() {..}

@Bean(name="second") 
MyBean getSecondBean(){..}

@Bean(name="third")
MyBean getThirdBean(){..}

@Autowired
@Qualifier("second")
public void usingTheSecondBeand( MyBean theSecondBean){..}
```